# DateTime2 Comparisons in SQL Editor and C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, datetime-format

I'm having real issues comparing datetimes in my SQL database. In SQL Server Manager 2014 I'll run something like the following:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  EmulationSessions
where StaffUser = 'person'
AND Active = 1
AND Created < '2017-02-05 15:38:13'
```

The row I expect to see looks like this:

[image]

But instead I get no result.

Similar attempts to match the format of the database in C# also fail when I convert current time like the following:

```
System.DateTime currentTime = System.DateTime.Now;
string currentTimeString = System.DateTime
                                    .Parse(currentTime.ToString(), new CultureInfo("en-AU"))
                                    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh24:mm:ss");
```

Is there another conversion step I'm missing?

Comment: ,Specify your sample data and expected result.

Comment: I included the expected result as an image since the formatting was weird, but here's what I expect from the SQL table:

Id    StaffUser Created                                 Active
1116    person         2017-05-02 15:14:09.427 1

Comment: @ScottGage in your expected result StaffUser doesn't correspond to 'where' expression

Comment: Your `where StaffUser = 'person'` clause is failing. Expected row has `StaffUser = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server defualt format is 'YYYY-MM-DD', In your case '02' is considered as month.
Check like this,

```
SELECT 
      *
    FROM 
      EmulationSessions
    where StaffUser = 'person'
    AND Active = 1
    AND Created < '2017-05-02 15:38:13'
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. My C# format was giving me that string and I was copying and pasting without much thought. That solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your query the date is being taken as string ,You must always use datetime datatype when making such comparisions. Try this

```
    SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  EmulationSessions
where StaffUser = 'person'
AND Active = 1
AND Created < Convert(datetime,'2017-02-05 15:38:13',112)
```

You can also use `CAST` to acheive the same.

Comment: it's not necessary to convert or cast